# The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, database, httpwebrequest

I'm working on application that take attendance records from attendance system and put it inside access file and upload to my web site.
it's working successfully but but when i focus on other screen in my desktop and go back to the application give this error ! 
"Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined"

This is the code:

```
public void BatchTransfert(zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1, int index, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string sdwEnrollNumber ="";
        int idwEnrollNumber = 0;
        int idwTMachineNumber = 0;
        int idwEMachineNumber = 0;
        int idwVerifyMode = 0;
        int idwInOutMode = 0;
        int idwYear = 0;
        int idwMonth = 0;
        int idwDay = 0;
        int idwHour = 0;
        int idwMinute = 0;
        int idwSecond = 0;
        int idwWorkcode = 0;

        int idwWorkCode = 0;
        int idwReserved = 0;

        int idwErrorCode = 0;
        int iGLCount = 0;
        int iIndex = 0;

        string time;
        string pcTime = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month).ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
        string userID;
        int AttStat;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable AttendanceLogs = new DataTable();
        DataColumn USERID = new DataColumn();
        USERID.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        USERID.ColumnName = "USERID";

        DataColumn CHECKTIME = new DataColumn();
        CHECKTIME.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        CHECKTIME.ColumnName = "CHECKTIME";

        DataColumn CHECKTYPE = new DataColumn();
        CHECKTYPE.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        CHECKTYPE.ColumnName = "CHECKTYPE";
        AttendanceLogs.Columns.Add(USERID);
        AttendanceLogs.Columns.Add(CHECKTIME);
        AttendanceLogs.Columns.Add(CHECKTYPE);

        ds.Tables.Add(AttendanceLogs);
        string sqlOnlineUpdate = "";
        string deviceIPAdress = "";
        try
        {

            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber[index], false);//disable the device
            if (axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber[index]))//read all the attendance records to the memory
            {

                while (axCZKEM1.IsTFTMachine(iMachineNumber[index]) ?
                        axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber[index], out sdwEnrollNumber, out idwVerifyMode, out idwInOutMode, out idwYear, out idwMonth,
                        out idwDay, out idwHour, out idwMinute, out idwSecond, ref idwWorkCode) //TFt machine
                        :
                        axCZKEM1.GetGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber[index], ref idwTMachineNumber, ref idwEnrollNumber, ref idwEMachineNumber, ref idwVerifyMode,
                        ref idwInOutMode, ref idwYear, ref idwMonth, ref idwDay, ref idwHour, ref idwMinute)) //ref idwSecond ref idwWorkCode))
                {
                    iGLCount++;
                    time = idwYear.ToString() + "-" + GetMonthName(idwMonth).ToString() + "-" + idwDay.ToString() + " " + idwHour.ToString() + ":" + idwMinute.ToString() + ":" + idwSecond.ToString();
                    pcTime = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month).ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
                    userID = axCZKEM1.IsTFTMachine(iMachineNumber[index]) ? sdwEnrollNumber : idwEnrollNumber.ToString();
                    AttStat = idwInOutMode;
                    DataRow newRow = AttendanceLogs.NewRow();
                    newRow["USERID"] = userID;
                    newRow["CHECKTIME"] = time;
                    newRow["CHECKTYPE"] = idwInOutMode;
                    AttendanceLogs.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }


                string filename = Application.StartupPath + "\\config.txt";
                Serializer serializeFromFile = new Serializer();
                settings = serializeFromFile.DeSerializeObject(filename);

                //axCZKEM1.Disconnect();
                axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber[index], true);//enable the device
                if (AttendanceLogs.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    progressBar1.Enabled = true;
                    progressBar1.Maximum = AttendanceLogs.Rows.Count;
                    progressBar1.Visible = true;
                    labelProgress.Visible = true;

                    String connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + settings.localDBPath;
                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                    conn.Open();
                    axCZKEM1.GetDeviceIP(iMachineNumber[index], ref deviceIPAdress);


                    string sqlSelect;
                    string queryString;
                    string onlineApp;
                    string urlAdress;


                    #region UploadData
                    foreach (DataRow row in AttendanceLogs.Rows)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                            {
                                e.Cancel = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                i++;
                                progressBar1.Value = i;
                                //Connection Info for Local DB                            
                                sqlSelect = "Select * from CHECKINOUT WHERE USERID = " + row["USERID"] + " and CHECKTIME = #" + row["CHECKTIME"] + "#  and CHECKTYPE = '" + row["CHECKTYPE"] + "'";
                                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlSelect, conn);
                                OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                //Saving in local Db
                                if (!dataReader.HasRows)
                                {

                                    queryString = "userID=" + row["USERID"] + "&time=" + row["CHECKTIME"] + "&AttStat=" + row["CHECKTYPE"] + "&pcTime=" + pcTime + "&schoolID=" + schoolID + "&schoolName=" + schoolName + "&machineName=" + machineName;

                                    onlineApp = settings.onlinURL + @"/Admin/HR/Attendance_UpdateData.ashx?" + queryString;
                                    urlAdress = onlineApp;
                                    Uri url = new Uri(urlAdress);
                                    HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                                    webReq.Method = "Get";

                                    HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
                                    if (myWebResponse.ContentLength == 7)
                                    {
                                        dataReader.Close();
                                        string sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO CHECKINOUT ( USERID, CHECKTIME, CHECKTYPE )"
                                                            + "VALUES (" + row["USERID"] + ", #" + row["CHECKTIME"] + "#, " + row["CHECKTYPE"] + ")";
                                        cmd.CommandText = sqlUpdate;
                                        dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                    }
                                    myWebResponse.Close();
                                }
                                labelProgress.Text = "Transfering data from device IP : " + deviceIPAdress + ".... " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + " / " + progressBar1.Maximum.ToString();   //row["USERID"];
                                labelProgress.Refresh();
                                dataReader.Close();
                                dataReader.Dispose();
                            }
                        }

                        catch (SqlException sqlExp)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(sqlExp.Message);
                            EventLog.WriteEntry("User ID", sqlExp.Message, EventLogEntryType.Information, 15);
                            SendMail("School : " + machineName + " / 'Method Batch Down' Error in Online database Conn : " + sqlExp.Message + "\n" + "Sql Query : " + sqlOnlineUpdate);
                        }

                        catch (Exception exp)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Herre Apear the Error!!!!!!!!" + exp.Message + "  +" + exp.HelpLink);
                            EventLog.WriteEntry("RFID finger Print", exp.Message, EventLogEntryType.Information, 15);
                            SendMail("School : " + machineName + " / 'Method Batch Down' Error in Transfert Data : " + exp.Message + "\n" + "Sql Query : " + sqlOnlineUpdate);
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                    //conn.Close();
                    //conn.Dispose();
                }

                //objConn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);

                if (idwErrorCode != 0 && idwErrorCode != -2)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Reading data from terminal failed,ErrorCode: " + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
                    SendMail("Reading data from terminal failed, ErrorCode: " + idwErrorCode.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    //SendMail("No data from terminal returns!, ErrorCode: " + idwErrorCode.ToString());
                }
            }
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber[index], true);
            labelProgress.Visible = false;
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {

            EventLog.WriteEntry("User ID", sqlEx.Message, EventLogEntryType.Information, 15);
            SendMail("School : " + machineName + " / 'Method Batch Down' Error in Online database Conn : " + sqlEx.Message + "\n" + "Sql Query : " + sqlOnlineUpdate);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("RFID finger Print", ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Information, 15);
            //SendMail("School : " + machineName + " / 'Method Batch Down' Error in Transfert Data : " + ex.Message + "\n" + "Sql Query : " + sqlOnlineUpdate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? Have you tried setting a breakpoint?

Comment: it's work without error, but when i make the application unfocus which mean "choose another application on my desktop error appear" !

Comment: So theres no error but you do something and that makes an error appear? where?

Comment: Here i think:
HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

Answer (score 2):

**Preface edit:**

It turned out that it wasn't any of this silly stuff. Instantiating a `Uri` requires an accompanying scheme. Calling `new Uri("example.com/path")` will result in this exception. Instead, you should call `new Uri("http://example.com/path")`. If that isn't the problem you're having, however, continue on...

I have no idea where this error is occurring to give more details, but it means you need to specify `UriKind` in the `Uri` constructor. For instance, `new Uri("/path")` might throw an error, and I'd specify `new Uri("/path", UriKind.Relative)` and that makes it work. So wherever you determine the error to be coming from, or wherever you call that constructor, add that.

**Edit:**

I see you call

```
Uri url = new Uri(urlAdress);
```

at one point. I'll bet'cha that's it. Just add in that parameter with whatever *kind* of value `urlAddress` is meant to be (it comes from your config file, but it's probably `UriKind.Absolute`) and you'll be golden.

Comment: i make it like that: Uri url = new Uri(urlAdress, UriKind.Relative);.... but an error apear also!!!...A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI

Comment: As I said, it's probably `UriKind.Absolute`. Absolute is when it specifies a domain (like http://www.facebook.com/me) as compared to just a path (like /me). Change it to absolute and I bet it'll work.

Comment: Same: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Comment: What exactly is the URI that you're passing?

Comment: http://example.com/KSA/demo.v4/Admin/HR/Attendance_UpdateData.ashx?userlD=1003&time=2013-December-31-space-14:41:0&AttStat=3&pcTime=2014-July-15-space-11:4:55&schoollD=1&schoolName=DigDyn&machineName=DigDyn

Comment: there is -space- in link .. i added it to bs clear to u

Comment: So...you know what the problem is? I don't understand what you're looking for now. If you're looking to Url Encode your query parameters, that can be accomplished through `Uri.EscapeUriString(string)`.

Comment: Although I still think the main problem here is your lack of a scheme. If you're being precise when you say that `urlAddress` is equal to `example.com/KSA/demo.v4/...`, then you need to add in the Uri Scheme at the beginning. Even just make it `Uri url = new Uri("http://" + urlAdress);`

Comment: solved ..
Finally i found the problem.
in foreach loop each time i refocus the application screen it disconnect from the config file that give me the link, so i make this flag:

    if (flagFirstTime==0)
                                        {
                                            onlineApp = settings.onlinURL + @"/Admin/HR/Attendance_UpdateData.ashx?" + queryString;
                                            urlAdress = onlineApp;
                                            flagFirstTime = 1;
                                        }

Comment: But...your `queryString` changes each time you go through the `foreach`. By doing that, you're cancelling out the advantage of looping through each user and making the call. It'll only ever happen for the first user. But if that works, then great.

Comment: not each time !, just first time because the flag prevent it to change !

Comment: But your `queryString` depends on `User`, and `User` changes in each iteration of the `foreach`. But again, if that works for you, if your tests succeed, then I certainly hold no issue with that.